# Ploting all the solutions of Solve : dots and curves together

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'd like to plot all the solutions of the following equation :

```
F[x_] = -x^2 + 3/4*x^4
MU[x_] = D[F[x], x]
PRESSION[x_] = -x^2 + 3/4*x^4 - x*(-2 x + 3 x^3)
sol = Solve[{y*PRESSION[y] == x* PRESSION[x] && MU[x] == MU[y]}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

There are many solutions, as curves or dots. I would like to plot all of them together. Can you help please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sols = {x, y} /.  Quiet[sol = 
     N@Solve[{y*PRESSION[y] == x*PRESSION[x] && MU[x] == MU[y]}, {x,  y}, Reals]];

{lines, points} = Pick[sols, Boole[FreeQ[Last@#, x]] & /@ sols, #] & /@ {0, 1};

ParametricPlot[lines, {x, -1, 1}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[points]}]
```

[image]